# subset of polynomials in with a single local maximum

Tags: polynomials

I need to fit a line to some data, but I need the fitted line to have a single local maximum.

I thought that if I could find the set of polynomials with a single global maximum, I could fit that and play with the degree of the polynomial to choose how tight to fit the data...

But I do not know what that subset looks like? Or if its even the best idea to approach the problem that way...

---

### Continuation

---

thanks smcc for putting me onto the idea to use that form... It was however not flexible enough so that led me to the following form..., 
$$
f(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^n \left(- \left|a_i \right| \left|x - b \right|^{max\left(1,p_i \right)}   \right) +c
$$

The reason I use the absolute values instead of saying that $a_i$ should be larger than zero, or that $p_i$ should be larger than or equal to one is so that when fitting the line I do not have to phrase the problem as a constrained optimisation.

Since I wanted to allow assymetry, I took this and put it in a piece wise function...
\begin{align*}
h(x)=
\begin{cases}
\sum_{i = 1}^{n_1} \left(- \left|a_i \right| \left|x - b \right|^{max\left(1+\epsilon,p_i \right)}   \right) + c & \text{for} \quad x < b \\
\sum_{j = 1}^{n_2} \left(- \left|d_j \right| \left|x - b \right|^{max\left(1+\epsilon,q_j \right)}   \right) + c & \text{for}  \quad x \ge b
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

The reason I include the $\epsilon$ is so that the point $(b,c)$ is smooth.

I find this form quite flexible...

Comment: Any strictly concave function has the property you want. So you can use polynomials of the form $-x^2$, $-x^4$, $-x^6$ etc with appropriate constants.

Answer (score 1):

Any strictly concave function has the property you want. You can use any polynomial of the form $$f(x)=-a(x-b)^n+c$$ where $n$ is an even natural number, $a>0$ and $c\in\mathbb{R}$. The maximum of $f$ is at $(b,c)$.